# fullcalendar dow is not working

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have tried different settings, but nothing seems to work, I need to repeat events on calendar, like all Sundays, Tuesdays. Here is my code:

```
 $('#appointment_calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            left:   'prev',
            center: 'today',    
            right:  'next'
        },
        events: [{
            title:"My repeating event",
            start: '10:00', 
            end: '14:00', 

            dow: [ 1, 4 ] 
        }],
    });
```

Have tried removing/adding tittle, start, end, ranges, nothing seems to works.

Comment: Can you share the link of your live site or codepen because I've tried the same code and it worked, maybe the fullcalendar js file is not included correctly on your page. @Niyojan

Comment: By the way, which version of fullcalendar you're working on? And here is the link of working Dow implementation [Fullcalendar Dow](https://codepen.io/Adeel91/pen/pPZXde)

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem and cannot for the life of me figure out why...

Answer (score 2):

In version 4 and above you have to use "**daysOfWeek**" instead of "dow".
Also you should use "**startTime**" and "**endTime**" instead of "start" and "end".

So your code should be change to :

```js
$('#appointment_calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            left:   'prev',
            center: 'today',    
            right:  'next'
        },
        events: [{
            title:"My repeating event",
            startTime: '10:00', 
            endTime: '14:00', 

            daysOfWeek: [ 1, 4 ] 
        }],
    });
```

Comment: true, but the code above in the question is clearly v3

Comment: Can we use daysOfWeek with date range (startdate and endDate) ?

Comment: @upendtu Yes, you can do it with adding "startRecur" and "endRecur" in the event block. Example: {startRecur: 2019-04-27T10:00:00+04:30, daysOfWeek: [ 1, 4 ] }

Answer (score 0):

**I have done some testing and it appears that FullCalendar fails with dow above version 3.4.0.**

The following code is identical but for the FullCalendar version.

---

### FullCalendar 3.4.0 (OK)

```html
<!doctype html>

<html class="no-js" lang="en">

    <head>

 <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
 
    </head>
 
    <body>
 
 <main>
  
     <div class="inner">
  <div class="full">
    
      <h1>Events Calendar</h1>
     
      <div id="calendar">
      </div>
     
      <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      
   // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
       
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     
    timezone: 'local',
    firstDay: 1,
    timeFormat: 'H:mm',
          
    events: [{
           
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: "2018-04-25T09:00:00",
        dow: [3,4,5]
     
    }]
     
       });
     
   });
             </script>
   
  </div>
     </div>
   
 </main>
   
    </body>
</html>
```

---

### FullCalendar 3.5.0 (FAIL)

```html
<!doctype html>

<html class="no-js" lang="en">

    <head>

 <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.5.0/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.5.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
 
    </head>
 
    <body>
 
 <main>
    
            <h1>Events Calendar</h1>
     
            <div id="calendar">
            </div>
     
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                        timezone: 'local',
                        firstDay: 1,
                        timeFormat: 'H:mm',

                        events: [{

                            title: 'All Day Event',
                            start: "2018-04-04T09:00:00",
                            dow: [3,4,5]

                        }]

                    });

                });
     </script>

        </main>
   
    </body>
</html>
```

[jsFiddle with FullCalendar v3.4](https://jsfiddle.net/indieweb/9opjqkr9/) (working)

[jsFiddle with FullCalendar v3.5](https://jsfiddle.net/indieweb/6kh8zg5m/) (failing)

Comment: In 3.5 you need to use "duration" times so instead of "2018-04-04T09:00:00" use just "09:00:00".

Comment: Interesting. So this then means you can't have a start date with dow...

Comment: Seems like you have to use the `ranges` property as well as `dow` but it doesn't mean the calendar does the checking for you. You need to implement an `eventRender` handler that returns boolean of whether each specific event should be displayed